# Dealloc is not called when Using JASidePanels

Tags: ios, memory-management

Im using JAsidepanels(https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels) to achieve side Menu option in my app, Recently I started searching memory managing of App.

I came to know that dealloc method should be called when we dismiss the view controller.

When I’m not using JASidepanel Dealloc method is called,

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) JASidePanelController *viewController;
```

This is how We are referencing “JASidePanelController”

What should i supposed to do to get dealloc called? 
Please help me..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is a dead library, I would suggest use another one, there are some suggestions there:

https://github.com/devindoty/DDMenuController

https://github.com/mystcolor/JTRevealSidebarDemo

https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController

https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck

https://github.com/pkluz/ZUUIRevealController

https://github.com/gresrun/GHSidebarNav

Check the date of the commits and people using it.

Personally I use ECSlidingViewController and MMDrawerController in my projects.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, i will go through them, But Im using in many  places  trough out of my project, there exists lots of views to make changes, Until i update to the new library, Is there any work around to get call dealloc

Comment: Paste some code and let's see, probably the error is in the logic. Try also the profiler (instruments) and use the Allocations instrument to see the lifetime.